# How to use libviso2?

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, error-handling, installation

I try to run visual odometry examples. I install libviso2 from [here](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso/). I have matlab 2011b. I use ubuntu 14.04.

Readme of libviso2 says that for c++ installation :

```
- sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev
- sudo apt-get install libpng++-dev

Linux:

1) Move to libviso2 root directory
2) Type 'cmake .'
3) Type 'make'
4) Run './viso2 path/to/sequence/2010_03_09_drive_0019'
```

I run libviso2 succesfully on terminal. Next step, I tried to run matlab wrappers and demos. Readme says that about matlab wrappers :

```
In the MATLAB directory of libviso, simply run 'make.m' to generate the mex wrappers.
(Run mex -setup before to choose your desired compiler)

Now try to run the demo*.m files!
```

Firstly, I run make.m.The output is below :

```
../src/triangle.cpp:1552:27: warning: format ‘%lx’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
        printtri.orient);
                       ^
../src/triangle.cpp:1561:42: warning: format ‘%lx’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
        printvertex[0], printvertex[1]);
                                      ^
../src/triangle.cpp:1568:42: warning: format ‘%lx’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
        printvertex[0], printvertex[1]);
```

Then I run `mex -setup`. I try to run a example demo, but I get an error. The error message is below :

```
MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version   `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by
/MATLAB/bin/libviso2/matlab/visualOdometryMonoMex.mexa64)
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Matlab changed for a 64 bit API. so add '-compatibleArrayDims' to mex file. I did this and it works. Hope it works for you as well.